# server name in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, message, server-name

when I want to use SQL server managment studio , I dont know what have to write in in server name . pleas help me [when I write "." it shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvQO4.png)

Comment: Did you actually install SQL Server? SQL Server Management Studio is just the interface, the database engine is a separate install.

Comment: by default it is dot (.) or your coumputer name

Comment: you could try '(local)'

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) shows Server name from installed SQLServer.
Uninstall SQLServer if you already installed or install SQLServer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

Once you reinstall SQLServer. Open SSMS on connect panel

1. Click on Server name dropdown
2. Select [Browse for servers]
3. Selected [Database Engine]

Choose your machine and that's it

Comment: `Browse for servers` [doesn't work](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127849/browse-for-servers-does-not-display-local-instance) in a lot of cases e.g. server is remote, best to just type the DNS name or IP address

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, many times it does fails to detect DB engines in networks. Specifying IP is a better approch